# Is it possible to build my Axon project like this?

Tags: architecture, axon

[image]

> FYI I'm just a beginner with Axon.

I'm trying to make my project look like the picture above, but I don't know if it's possible.

Because I sent the command from Application A to Application C and worked on several tasks (e.g saving entity, handling events, commands etc) from Application C, and various information was stored in the `SAGA_ENTRY` table of C's h2 DB. But I think this information should be shared with other applications. But I don't think it's possible to share. That's why I think I designed it wrong.

I wonder if I can keep doing this. Is this a bad design and a waste of time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the design per se, looking at the picture only. It shows 3 (different) applications talking to each other through Axon Server, using it as a Message Bus and an Event Store.

But to the question about how to design a Saga, it really depends.
In Axon Framework, a Saga can be seen as a Process Manager so the Application which will store the info (on it's own Saga table) is the Process Manager and is the only one responsible to handle it. It should be getting Commands from anywhere (other applications can send commands to it) and should be handling it in the best way.

Basically, if you have a Saga on Application A that will fire Commands to be handled by Application B or C, sure - that is fine. This same Saga can listen to Commands from Application B or C to decide if it should fire additional Commands or to finish the Saga.

Hope that clarifies a bit.
KR,

Comment: Thank you for your answering.
I'm currently using  Orchestration-Based Saga
and if Saga is manged by Application A , it would be okay to have Saga Table in only Application A?
because I don't want Application B or C have Saga Table

Comment: Yes, of course it is. Saga table is used to store the (in progress) Sagas, so it makes total sense to have it only where you are going to use it.